# how to Stateful (REST API) implement with angular?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, rest, ionic5, opencart-3

I have never used Stateful REST API in any project, but now I am stuck with it and I don't have any idea how to handle it with angular (ionic 5).

There are many questions, how to manage Cookie and how it is sent with every request header, I have checked almost every possibility but still facing issues.

REST API is Developed in OpenCart (PHP Framework).

**HTTP call method**

```
public POST(url: string, data: any): Observable<any> {
try {
  if (this.networkService.getCurrentNetworkStatus() === ConnectionStatus.Offline) {
    this.toast.toastShow(`No internet connectivity. Please try again later.`);
  } else {
    return this.http.post<responseModel>(url , data).pipe(
      map((response) => {
        return response;
      }),
      catchError(async (error) => this.handleErrors(error, this.globalVar.apiUrl + url + this.globalVar.urlKey))
    );
  }
} catch (error) {
  return of(null);
}}
```

**Interceptor**

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
if (this.globalVar.loginInfo !== '') {
  req = req.clone({
    headers: req.headers.append('observe', 'response' as 'response')
  });
}

return next.handle(req).pipe(
  map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
    if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      const camelCaseObject = mapKeys(event.body, (v: any, k: any) => camelCase(k));
      const modEvent = event.clone({ body: camelCaseObject });
      return modEvent;
    }
  })
);}
```

**API Calling Function**

```
login() {
this.http.Login(RequestBody).subscribe((response) => {
 console.log(response)
}, (err) => {
  console.log('', err);
});}
```

this is the standard structure of angular which is I am following.

please help.

Answer (score 0):

after some analyses and R&D, I have found the solution from the backend side, actually, we have changed request-header and response-header related configuration from web-service/API.

thanks.